# Connect to a System DSN via UCanAccess

Tags: scala, jdbc, odbc, dsn, ucanaccess

I'm currently upgrading a project from Java 7 to Java 8, thus I switched from using the JDBC-ODBC Bridge to using UCanAccess. The database I want to connect to is registered as a system DSN so I connected to it like this:

```
Database.forURL("jdbc:odbc:MyDB" + ";DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;charSet=Cp1250", driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver")
```

Now I changed that to

```
Database.forURL("jdbc:ucanaccess:MyDB" + ";DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;charSet=Cp1250", driver = "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver")
```

but that gives me the error:

```
Driver net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver does not know how to handle URL jdbc:ucanaccess:MyDB;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;charSet=Cp1250
```

Is there a way to access a DSN via UCanAccess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to access a DSN via UCanAccess?

Not directly. UCanAccess is a JDBC driver that does not use ODBC, so it has no knowledge of ODBC DSNs.

Your UCanAccess connection string needs to include the path to the Access database file, e.g.,

```
jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/path/to/mydata.accdb
```

If necessary, you could retrieve that file path from the configuration information for an ODBC DSN. On Windows, the information for a System DSN named `MyDB` would be in the Windows registry under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\MyDb
```

or perhaps

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI\MyDb
```